# Tooltip for a DIV element created on the serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, qtip

I have multiple DIV elements that are created on the server side and then later rendered on the client side using ASP .Net MVC Html.Raw Helper method. I am looking to add a popup on a mouseover. The content of popup for each DIV element is different. How can I do this with JQuery or qTip?. here are my sample DIV elements. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
<div class="gantt" style="border-width:medium;border-color:black;background:green;width:2%;margin-left:10%;">11</div>
<div class="gantt" style="border-width:medium;border-color:black;background:green;width:7%;margin-left:12%;">11</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how I could create the text for the popup on server-side and then later use JQuery to show it as a popup on mouseover.

Comment: why not reading qTip documentation? http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/

Comment: @Raminson. Sorry for not being clear. Actually the DIV elements are created at runtime on the server and then rendered on to the browser using ASP .Net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

qTip provides AJAX calls as well so you can get the content that has to be rendered inside the popup from server.

A simple example

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
        ajax: {
            url: '/path/to/file', // URL to the local file
            type: 'GET', // POST or GET
            data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
        }
    }
});
```

You can read much from [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/plugins/ajax/)